# How do I use the openssl command to decode a certificate/public key .PEM file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls, public-key, public-key-encryption

I have my localhost TSL/SSL certificate from Chrome stored to a .PEM file.  Was wondering how do I use the oppenssl command to decode it into a list of human-readable fields.

Googling this only returned info on how to work with the private key.

There are online utilities for decoding a public key, but I need a method I can easily access programatically using Python.  I couldn't find anyway to do this using a library, so I thought the openssl command might work.

The public key text in the .PEM file is the standard public key format that does work in the online decoding utilities.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to change your title to state that you want to view a certificate, not a public key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to view a public key in PKCS#1 format, you can use:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in <file> -text
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer if the input is indeed just the public key in a file. because if you don't add the `-pubin` parameter, `openssl rsa ...` will emit something like `asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag` and `asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error`. If you have full X509 certificate instead of just the public key, then `openssl x509 ...` will show the data even without the `-pubin` parameter.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I changed it to this answer

Answer (score 14):

> how do I use the oppenssl command to decode it into a list of human-readable fields.

`openssl x509 -in NAME.pem -text -noout`

Replace 'NAME' with whatever filename your .pem file has.

Comment: That shows a X509 certificate, not public key.